# Canvas Game Animation

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I a making a game and got the idea of having a semi transparent png animation from a spritesheet to appear when the player gets put back to the start after he dies.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2Vwyqo_y_A

It's just I have never gotten around to animation yet a for some reason I think the manipulating the animrequestframe thingy kinda confusing. I have it set so my game refreshes every 60 times a second.

Would love some advice to help me out! :/
It's my first 'proper' game!

Comment: This [list of JS game engines](https://gist.github.com/bebraw/768272) might be a good point to start.

Comment: I plan on using impactjs for my next game, it's just everything I wanted to do so far can be done with pure js! :) An engine would prob save me a ton of time though :)

Comment: @Sam If the following answer was of any help, please consider marking it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're struggling getting your head around `requestFrameAnimation`, I suggest you read these couple of links, they explain it really well:

1. [The secret to silky smooth JavaScript animation!](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/)
2. [Using requestAnimationFrame](http://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/)

The simplest example given:

```
function gameLoop() {
  // Game logic
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

**EDIT:** You mention you want your game to run every at 60 FPS. Request animation will run your game as fast as it can - which is a good thing - but there are tricks to set the actual FPS. However, unless you're aiming for a lower FPS, like 30, I wouldn't bother.